# regex for integer or floating point number with two decimals

Tags: regex

I want to validate my currency field with regex. I want to allow the following pattern entries

```
1.23
1
.45
0.56
56.00
```

No comma should be allowed. I've tried `\d+(\.\d\d)` but it allows only first, fourth and fifth entries. `\d+(?:\.\d\d+)?` allows all but third one.

Comment: Have you tried \d*(\.\d*)  ?

Comment: How are that currencies? I only see floats.

Comment: @Melanie: It does not allows `12` but allows `12.`

Comment: @Bergi: You are right. they are actually floats. but I want t allow only two decimal places or those entries that match the given pattern

Comment: @Krishanu: "Exactly two" decimals or "more than two" decimals (like in your second pattern)?

Comment: @Bergi: either no decimal or exactly two decimal. But anyway, I got my answer. thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\d*` instead of `\d+` before the decimal to match zero or more digits.  Also add anchors (`^` and `$`) or else it will pass as long as there is any match available. This would also validate an empty string, so if necessary you can use a lookahead to make sure there is at least one digit:

```
^(?=.*\d)\d*(?:\.\d\d)?$
```

Comment: Your solution works well. but it allows `1.254` and `23.1`. I want to allow only two decimal places. Either there will be no decimal or only two decimal

Comment: @KrishanuDey that was unclear to me; I updated it so `\d+` is `\d\d`

Answer (score 2):

[Regexes for floating-point numbers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) are a solved problem:

```
\d*\.?\d+
```

For at least two decimals:

```
(\d*\.\d)?\d+
```

To make it more comprehensible:

```
\d+|\d*\.\d{2,}
```

And for exactly two decimals:

```
\d+|\d*\.\d{2}
```

Depending on your language, don't forget to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the expression so that it must match the whole string.